# Distribute nodes evenly around central node using a relative SVG width and height

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am playing around with the `D3` library and have the following snippet of code which sets the coordinates of the nodes:

```
node.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { 
    return d.x; 
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { 
    return d.y; 
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10; })
  .style("fill", color)
  .on("click", click)
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
  .call(force.drag);
```

View [Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ip8gqTbHk1rIyoQY4TDP?p=preview)

I want to evenly distribute the child nodes around the parent node so that the data is spread maximising the space of the SVG - these currently cluster together despite attempts to adjust the `"cy"` and `"cx"` properties and increasing the size of the individual nodes through the `"r"` property.

Comment: Are you looking to just increase the [link distance](http://plnkr.co/edit/RBx8PXhsINQGdHWs3Vce?p=preview) - docs [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#linkDistance)?

Comment: Ah yes, this works together with the [charge()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#charge) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this, I updated two default method properties on the `Force Layout`, those being [.linkDistance()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#linkDistance) and [.linkCharge()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#charge)

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
.linkDistance(80)
.charge(-500);
```

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

Thanks to @Mark for his references to the [Force Layout Documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#charge).